# Ruby Method similar to Haskells cycle

Tags: ruby, haskell, functional-programming

Is there a Ruby method similar to Haskell's cycle? Haskell's cycle takes a list and returns that list infinitely appended to itself. It's commonly used with take which grabs a certain number of elements off the top of an array. Is there a Ruby method that takes an array and returns the array appended to itself some n number of times?

Comment: Just for reference, cycle is given by: `cycle xs = xs' where xs' = xs ++ xs'` which is beautiful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle). From the documentation:

```
Array.cycle

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.cycle(n=nil) {|obj| block }  -> nil
  ary.cycle(n=nil)                 -> an_enumerator


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Calls block for each element repeatedly n times or forever if none
or nil is given.  If a non-positive number is given or the array is empty, does
nothing.  Returns nil if the loop has finished without getting interrupted.

If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

  a = ["a", "b", "c"]
  a.cycle {|x| puts x }  # print, a, b, c, a, b, c,.. forever.
  a.cycle(2) {|x| puts x }  # print, a, b, c, a, b, c.
```

---

Edit:

> It seems like whats inside the block is basically a "Lambda", and as far as I know, I can't make a lambda concat each element onto an existing array.

```
b = [1, 2, 3]
z = []
b.cycle(2) { |i| z << i }
z # => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Funny what happens when you Read The Fine Manual, eh?

Comment: Magic things happen; Mysterious methods appear that were never there before. :-)

Comment: I read the manual. This does not seem do what Haskell's cycle does. I'm somewhat new to Ruby, so I can't really see how to make cycle do what I want. It seems like whats inside the block is basically a "Lambda", and as far as I know, I can't make a lambda concat each element onto an existing array.

Comment: @Josh: I suspect the difference between `*` and `cycle` will depend on how you use the result, if you want to consume or iterate over the produce array immediately then `cycle` with a block would have the same effect as `(a * n).each { ... }`. And there are more iteration methods available beyond `each`, things like `each_with_object` or `inject` might do what you're trying to do.

Comment: A bit late for the party, but Ruby also has `take`, so you can do something like `b.cycle.take(10)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply an array by an integer using [`Array#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2A):

> **ary * int → new_ary**
>
> [...] Otherwise, returns a new array built by concatenating the `int` copies of `self`.

So you can do things like this:

```
>> [1, 2] * 3
=> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: +1, personally, this is how I'd do it usually. `cycle` might be "lazy" though, or at least not generate an intermediate array like `*` will.

Comment: @theTinMan: I suspect that `cycle` is lazy since both `a.cycle` and `a.cycle(n)` are `Enumerator`s. I'd use `*` if I knew how many I needed and `cycle` if I didn't.